# Cross-validation and model selection of ANN

Tags: neural-networks, classification, cross-validation, model-selection

I have a neural network that I use to classify data into a number of classes; in my particular case, the classes are imbalanced, but I am trying to understand this for the general case. I am using F1 score as the metric for evaluating the network. I also would like to perform K-fold cross-validation.

So, let's say I have 1000 data points and I split them into 900 training and 100 test set, which I will use for evaluation only.

I then run a K-fold cross-validation; for simplicity let's assume K=3.

I take the training set (900 elements), use the first 600 elements for training and the other 300 for validation. I then take the middle 300 elements for validation and, finally the last 300.
At each fold, I will

1. Save the best-performing model (according to the validation set)
2. Evaluate this best-performing model on the test set.

Ok, so let's say I get these F1 scores

| fold | train F1 | val F1 | test F1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.93 | 0.88 | 0.87 |
| 2 | 0.95 | 0.93 | 0.86 |
| 3 | 0.94 | 0.91 | 0.92 |
| **Average** | **0.94** | **0.91** | **0.88** |
| **SD** | **0.01** | **0.03** | **0.03** |

I have a few questions.

1. Is the procedure above correct?
2. When reporting the model accuracy, is it OK to just report the average, so for example, $F1 = 0.88 \pm 0.03$?
3. Now, let's say I am happy with the model and I want to use it to classify some new data. Which model should I use? Should I pick the model trained in fold 3, since it has the highest score on the test data? But the one trained in fold 2, had a higher score on the validation data, so am I not biasing my choice based on the arbitrarily-picked characteristic of my test set?
4. Finally, let's say that now I decide I want to change some hyperparameter or change the network structure etc. I repeat the steps above and get a "better" model, based on the evaluation on the same test set. How can I be confident that this new model is really better on a new dataset and I am not just seeing a fluke in how the test set was picked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 2 look good!

For 3, you should choose the model based off of **validation** set results. Since you’ve done multiple folds, you can take the hyper parameters that returned the **highest average validation** accuracy as best. The test set should be a complete hold out as an estimate to see how it will do when deployed. Another common practice is once you have run cross-validation, you would **retrain the neural network** (with the best hyperparameters) on the training+validation data, since the more data fed into these models, the better.

For 4, You would do the same process as above, and only use the test set as a gauge, rather than using it to choose a better model.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense!